# Besides a declarative language, is SQL a functional language?

Tags: sql, functional-programming

Why yes or why not?

Answer (score 36):

`SQL` was designed as a declarative language, in sense that you tell `what` you want to get and the `SQL` engine decides `how`.

However, `SQL` operates on sets, and the results of the functions can be first class sets in `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL`.

One can say that `SQL` is functional language, as long as a function takes a set as its input and produces a set as its output.

That is, you can write something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable t
JOIN    myfunction(x) f
ON      f.col1 = t.col2
```

, or even this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable t
CROSS APPLY
        myfunction(t.col2) f
```

(in `SQL Server`)

or this:

```
SELECT  t.*, myfunction(t.col2)
FROM    mytable t
```

(in `PostgreSQL`)

This is not a part of `SQL` standard, though.

Just like a `C++` compiler tries to find an optimal way to multiply two `float`s (in terms of plain algebra), `SQL` optimizer tries to find an optimal ways to multiply two sets (in terms of relational algebra).

In `C++`, you just write `a * b` and rely on compiler to generate an optimal assembly for this.

In `SQL`, you write `SELECT * FROM a NATURAL JOIN b` and rely on optimizer.

However, with all `SQL`'s declared declarativity (no pun intended), most real optimizers are able to do only very basic query rewrites.

Say, no optimizer I'm aware of is able to use same efficient plan for this query:

```
SELECT  t1.id, t1.value, SUM(t2.value)
FROM    mytable t1
JOIN    mytable t2
ON      t2.id <= t1.id
GROUP BY
        t1.id, t1.value
```

and for this one:

```
SELECT  id, value, SUM(t1.value) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM    mytable
```

, to say nothing of more complex queries.

That's why you still need to formulate your queries so that they use an efficient plan (while still producing the same result), thus making `SQL` quite a bit less of a declarative language.

I recently made post in my blog on this:

- [**Double-thinking in SQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/12/double-thinking-in-sql/)

Comment: to be functional, a function would have to be allowed to take a function as input though. simply allowing functions to exist is hardly enough.

Comment: @jalf: like in `functionA(x) CROSS APPLY functionB(functionA.col1)`?

Answer (score 15):

No, SQL is not a functional language.  The paradigm is somewhat different.  Note that there are other types of declarative programming languages other than functional - the canonical example being logic programming and PROLOG.

Technically, Relational Algebra (the theoretical basis of SQL) is not actually turing complete.  Although modern SQL dialects add enough procedural features so that one can implement stored procedures and are turing complete at this level, a single SQL query is not a turing complete computation.   Relational Algebra has the property of godel completeness.  Godel completeness implies the ability to express any computation that can be defined in terms of first order predicate calculus  - basically what you would know as ordinary logical expressions.

Answer (score 9):

Are functions first-class objects in SQL? hardly. So I'd say no.

Comment: by definition - no, but similar by the way of thinking (and debugging)

Comment: Every SQL query is a function. Maybe you just don't like the syntax.

Comment: Yes they are... SELECT is a function. If you read about relational algebra you would know SELECTION and PROJECTION are functions/actions. You just don't see it written as `Select(columns/expressions)`;

Answer (score 4):

I think SQL and functional languages are very different from each other. In a functional language computation is done by evaluating functions. Functions do not mutate state. All they do is compute a value from their arguments. I other words, functions do not cause side-effects. Functional languages are general purpose.

SQL is a language designed for dealing with relational database management systems. It can be viewed as a Domain Specific Language. It is designed to work on "sets" of data. It can mutate global state (i.e, the database) by using commands like UPDATE. There is no concept of functions getting evaluated to a value. As far as I understand, SQL is not even Turing complete.

Comment: Functional languages have to cause side effects somehow, don't they?

Answer (score 4):

Declarative and functional? That would be a spreadsheet.

Comment: Nonsense.  Spreadsheets don't let you pass around functions as first class objects.  The question is, does SQL allow functions to be passed around. It does, to a certain extent.  But not enough for many of the usual functional programming techniques to apply.

Comment: @nomen IIRC my answer was a pun. Tell me, in the 12 years since, have we agreed what 'SQL' means? If it's relations and relational operators then no, "passing functions around" isn't "allowed". But who knows what crazy things a SQL product will let you do with its proprietary code? Not me.

Comment: A function is a set of ordered tuples that satisfies certain regarding its values.  You can definitely pass those around, as select statements.  Certainly, this is not a very convenient interface to passing functions around.  Which was my point -- even ANSI sql exposes some functionalism, but not enough for the usual functional programming techniques to apply.  You can even do recursion in SQL-99.

Answer (score 3):

Not generally speaking, as without extensions to the syntax (e.g. PL/SQL, T-SQL), you can't write functions.

But it is certainly very expression-oriented, which is a feature it has in common with functional languages.

Answer (score 3):

There's no single true definition of what a functional language is (or for that matter, what a procedural or object-oriented one is).

But I can't really think of much that points to SQL being functional.
It doesn't have functions, it doesn't have recursion, it doesn't have closures, it doesn't have nested functions, it doesn't have functions as first-class types.

A more commonly asked question is whether SQL is a programming language *at all*. It's not turing-complete.

Comment: +1 for the not turing complete - I was just going to add that to my answer :-(

Comment: SQL92 standard is not turing complete. Oracle's PL/SQL and SQL Server's T-SQL and others are turing complete.

Comment: yes, but the question was about SQL itself, not the various vendors' extensions.

Answer (score 3):

In a sense: yes, SQL is functional.
Look at

- `SELECT` as `map()`,
- `WHERE` as `filter()`,
- `ORDER BY` as `sort()`,
- `DISTINCT` as `set()`

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.  A SQL Query maps one set of data (ie, data from tables) to another (the result set).

In mathematics, a function is basically a mapping from one set to another.

Thus, a query is a function, and since queries are first class citizens in SQL, therefore SQL is a functional language.

Answer (score 0):

Since the point of a functional language is that you program with, well, functions, I would say no. SQL is programming with relations (if you can even call SQL a programming language - in it's basic form, SQL is not Turing complete).