# Changing the column order in composite index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72284/

I'm reading this sqlservercentral article where they're querying using this.

```
SELECT *
    FROM Person.Contact
    WHERE FirstName = 'Helen'
        AND LastName = 'Meyer';
GO
```

and to make the above search faster they created following index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FullName
            ON Person.Contact
    ( LastName, FirstName );
GO
```

I'm not able to figure out in where clause we've first firstname then lastname.
and in index it's opposite order (lastname, firstname)

How does it makes difference here when we create composite index.
I know lastname will be sorted first then firstname will be sorted.

I checked the statistics by creating index in both ways (lastname,firstname)
and (firstname, lastname).

(lastname, firstname) approach is slightly faster, I want to know WHY where clause order and index column order is opposite?

Comment: In case, it makes no difference what order the index is in. The one you have works for searches on (`LastName, FirstName`) when both are specified, and it works equally well on searches that specify only the `LastName`. However: it will **not** help if you search on just `FirstName`. For a composite index to work, you have to specify the n left-most columns of the index in your `WHERE` clause (here: either 1 or 2 left-most).

Comment: @marc_s If i create composite index on 5 columns `Comp_IX (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)` then either I can specify all 5 column or only left most `col1` so it'll do index seek, m i right?

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi: if you have such an index, you can search on `col1`, or `col1` and `col2`, or `col1` and `col2` and `col3` - and so forth. But you **cannot** search on just `col3`, or on `col2` and `col5` - the **n left-most columns** (as written in your index definition) **must be included in your WHERE clause** - otherwise the index is useless

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server (and most RDBMS) will ignore the order of WHERE conditions.

This happens because SQL is a declarative language: you say what you want not how to do it. So the query optimiser will rearrange the WHERE conditions to match suitable indexes.

Note here you'll have a key lookup to the clustered index in the query plan to get the rest of the columns that are not in the index because it isn't covering.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote? Or point out what is wrong? Or just an anonymous coward? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153397/besides-a-declarative-language-is-sql-a-functional-language and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200319/is-sql-declarative back me up here...