# Can PL/pgSQL return a function from a function? Or even a set of functions?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, chaining, method-chaining, chain

Can I declare a PL/pgSQL function where the return type is a function?  Or even a set of functions?  Is there even a function *type* in the language?

I was noodling with the idea of a library of PL/pgSQL functions that could handle function chaining to make using the library easier.  Syntax akin to method dispatch isn't possible, but returning a function from a function should allow for some basic syntax magic.  Unfortunately I don't have enough of a mastery of PL/pgSQL yet to try to describe what I'm asking in a code example, I hope the question is clear enough as stated.

A variant of this question, [Is SQL a functional language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153397/besides-a-declarative-language-is-sql-a-functional-language) was asked 8 years ago, but my question is a little more specific (besides, the #1 answer on that question is incorrect!).

Comment: I'd say no. further question would be can table hold a table? can index index the index. and can sequence sequence the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a datatype to represent function references: [`regprocedure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html).

What there *isn't*, as far as I'm aware, is a way to use such a reference to directly invoke the function. I think the best you could do is to construct a `SELECT` statement which calls the function, and run it via [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). At this point, it's not a whole lot different to simply passing function names around as strings (though using `regprocedure` does mean that case-folding and overload resolution are all handled for you).

There's probably not a lot you could do without knowing something about the function's inputs and outputs, so you would probably want to familiarise yourself with the [`pg_proc` catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html).

Comment: This and @klin's answers really help a lot.  Any sense of why this exists, if it can't provide something that you can invoke directly?

Comment: @bartgrantham: Like any other type of database object, functions have an internal identifier which serves as their primary key in the catalog tables. The [alias types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) just provide a convenient way of mapping between object names and IDs, while taking into account schema search paths, rules around case sensitivity, etc. They're extremely useful when writing catalog queries, but I think that's generally all they're intended for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which returns set of references to the system catalog `pg_proc`, e.g.:

```
create or replace function get_function(name text)
returns setof regprocedure language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return query 
    select oid::regprocedure
    from pg_proc
    where proname = name;
end $$;
```

The above function can be used to extract information about functions with a given name, e.g.:

```
select get_function('get_function');

    get_function    
--------------------
 get_function(text)
(1 row)

select get_function('regexp_split_to_table'); -- overloaded function

                     get_function                      
-------------------------------------------------------
 regexp_split_to_table(text,text)
 regexp_split_to_table(text,text,text)
(2 rows)
```

It seems you could try to use this mechanism to dynamically execute retrieved functions in plpgsql code. It is not obvious however how to pass arguments in these calls. Probably it will not be without some text manipulations which may question the whole idea.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was hoping to learn.  It sure is clunky, though.  Maybe I'll give it a go.  Agreed about the parameter passing... seems like a recipe for suffering.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can. There is a type created implicitly for every table, which reflects the row structure of the table; but there's nothing equivalent for functions.